# Validating password in my application from Yii2 website

Tags: android, hash, yii2, salt

Me and my friend are working on final project. My friend is a little bit ahead and made all his database on Yii2 framework.

Everything worked fine, our database is on AWS and I got it by simple requests on my Android app.

Now I came to the part where I need to use login-password. Here I'm stuck, because all I can fetch from database is salted password. My friend used salt on the password part (which is the right thing to do).

The website is still on our hard drive.

1) Do we have to upload it online and only afterward to develop some
    API function that calls to database, so my app can access validation
    part of the website?

2) Maybe Yii2 already has a validation function
    build-in somewhere that can be used by Android app? An example would
    be super-helpful.

3) I saw a lot of examples about API functions,
    but all of them look pretty complicated and not related to Java at
    all.

Yii2 validation is actually online here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/blob/master/base/Security.php on validatePassword function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement IdentityInterface on your user model?
if yes, than you can use this in your yii2 rest api.

```
public function actionLoginUser(){
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $username = $data['username'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    $user = User::findByUsername($username);
    if($user->validatePassword($password)){
     //your next response 
    }        
}
```

Where validatePassword method is like this:

```
public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you be more specific and say how this method can be called from Java?